# Best way to use Rand() when creating dummy data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making up some dummy data for some tables. For columns that are ints this is easy enough. I have a few columns that are just enums, and I'm trying to figure out how to randomize them. I'm trying to replicate this kind of logic, but for SQL

```
CASE RAND()
WHEN BETWEEN (0,.3) THEN 'Apple'
WHEN BETWEEN (.31, .6) THEN 'Orange'
WHEN BETWEEN (.61, 1) THEN 'Banana'
```

This is in an insert statement, so right now for some other columns I have

```
INSERT INTO Table Values ('1', 'a', CASE Rand() WHEN > .3 THEN 'firstEnum' ELSE 'secondEnum')
```

I want to get this for more then just two enums.

I'll be using What is the correct way to actually do this? I assume there's a much better way, but I have very limited SQL experience.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to buy http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/.  I use there toolbelt and they make excellent tools for a reasonable price.  If you can not afford that I would suggest looking through Codeplex or GitHub.  Check out this question as well for more informaton [Looking for a SQL test set generator, ideally open source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579662/looking-for-a-sql-test-set-generator-ideally-open-source)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform something like this, I tested this in SQL Server 2012 but if it does not suite your needs I gladly post other solutions.

```
DECLARE @ListofIDs TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @ListofIDs
VALUES('Jeff'),('John'),('Mike'),('Chris'),('Tom'),('Fred');
SELECT top (1) IDs FROM @ListofIDs order by NEWID();
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you generate random text by

```
BEGIN
-- get a random varchar ascii char 32 to 128
DECLARE @RandomText VARCHAR(160)
DECLARE @length INT
SELECT @RandomText = ''
SET @length = CAST(RAND() * 160 as INT)
WHILE @length <> 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT @RandomText = @RandomText + CHAR(CAST(RAND() * 96 + 32 as INT))
    SET @length = @length - 1
END
print(@RandomText)
END
```